# How to sum with missing values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to sum Pandas Series objects, but I get weird results that seem not to be what the documentation says.

In Pandas 0.19.2, the following code:

```
a = pd.Series({1: 2, 3: 4})
b = pd.Series({3: 5, 4: 6})
print(a + b)
```

gives me,

```
1    NaN
3    9.0
4    NaN
dtype: float64
```

however, the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html) says:

> When summing data, NA (missing) values will be treated as zero

This seems to treat them as NaN rather than zeros.  I was expecting the output:

```
1    2.0
3    9.0
4    6.0
dtype: float64
```

In my case the Series comes from `value_counts()` over several columns and I wanted to use `sum()` but it gives me NaN for all rows that don't have values in all columns, which is wrong.  There should be an integer for every row.

Another mystery for me is why the result has dtype float:

```
a.dtype, b.dtype, (a+b).dtype
```

gives,

```
(dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('float64'))
```

which is quite surprising to me.

Edit: if I make sure that `a` and `b` have the same rows, then the resulting dtype is `int64`.  So the change to float is clearly just to allow for the NaN value, which is a bit shocking.

Edit 2: Fix mistake in the expected output.

Comment: The problem isn't missing values, it's that the indices don't match. The whole point of `pandas` data-structures is automatic index alignment.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I want to treat missing indexes as missing values, for which the documentation says they should be treated as zero.  Is it a bug in Pandas or in the documentation?

Comment: "When summing data, NA (missing) values will be treated as zero" is talking about the `sum` method.

Comment: You might also look up how to impute missing data.

Comment: > '"When summing data, NA (missing) values will be treated as zero" is talking about the sum method.' So this doesn't apply to `+` operator?  So I can not use it with the Python `sum()` method?  (ps., this is an _answer_. why on every question I ask do SO people insist on putting answers in the comments?)

Comment: No it doesn't apply to the vectorized addition wiht the `+` operator. I'm not sure what you mean with "Python's" `sum()` "method", do you mean the built-in function `sum`?

Comment: Yes, the built-in function `sum`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The claim from the documentation refers to reducing sums, i.e:

```
>>> a + b
1    NaN
3    9.0
4    NaN
dtype: float64
>>> (a + b).sum()
9.0 # nans treated as zero...
```

Not vectorized sums. You'll have to do this explicitely:

```
>>> (a + b).fillna(0)
1    0.0
3    9.0
4    0.0
dtype: float64
```

As for the promotion to `float`, that is a common `pandas` gotcha, which you can read about [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/gotchas.html#nan-integer-na-values-and-na-type-promotions)

Given your problem description, i.e. summarizing value counts across columns, you *may* want to add a `fill_value` to the addition, which the `pd.Series.add` method lets you do:

```
>>> a.add(b, fill_value=0)
1    2.0
3    9.0
4    6.0
dtype: float64
```

Note, unfortunately, it still does type-promotion due to `NaN`s. If it is an issue you can easily fix it:

```
>>> a.add(b, fill_value=0).astype(np.int)
1    2
3    9
4    6
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I made a mistake in my question!  Sorry.  I meant to write that last part.  fill_value was what I wanted, thank you.

Comment: Can you add to your answer, is there a nicer way to do, a.add(b..).add(c..) etc.?  This point of this was to handle summing across multiple series using sum(), i.e., avoiding a loop.

Comment: @Steve i'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do. If you add an example, taht would help clarify. If you meant you were using the built-in `sum`, then you probably should just do a loop.

Comment: That is, instead of b, I have a list [b,c,d,e...].  Anyways, I can do it with reduce, but it's just not as nice as sum():  total = reduce(lambda x,y: x.add(y,fill_value=0).astype(int), counts.values())

Comment: @Steve I would just use a for-loop... but reduce works.